# How to solve this proportion?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

There was X amount of workers. Together they got 120 (currency). If you decrease amount of workers by 4. EACH of workers would get triple of amount. How many workers are in total?

I thought that you can solve this like this

```
X = 120
X-4= ((120/X) * 3)* x-4
```

This might be nonsense. I got 0 as solution soo, It's not the right way.

How can you solve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess "the whole way" is this...

The first thing to do is simplify the original equation. 
$$
3∗(120/X)=120/(X−4)  
$$
You can do this by dividing both sides by 120. Now you get
$$
3/X=1/(X−4)  
$$
Now you need to get rid of the fractions. You can do that by multiplying both sides of the equation with the denominators of the fractions. These are the steps:
First multiply by both sides with (X-4) to get rid of the right-hand fraction.
$$
((X-4)*3)/X=1
$$
Then multiply both sides with X to get rid of the left-hand fraction.
$$
(X-4)*3=X
$$
Now simply perform the multiplication.
$$
3*X-12=X  
$$
$$
3*X-X=12  
$$
$$
2*X=12 
$$
$$
X=6  
$$

Answer (score 2):

You want to solve

$$3 * (120/X) = 120/(X-4)$$

The left hand side is 3 times the amount each of them is currently getting, and the right hand side is the amount each of them would get if there were 4 fewer workers.

Comment: Sorry, but can you show me whole way?